# Не получается использовать JAVA_HOME в cmd

Tags: java, cmd

Я пытаюсь использовать переменную `JAVA_HOME` для перехода в директорию jdk/bin/, но командная строка выводит "Системе не удается найти указанный путь". Команда `set` (без аргументов) не выводит `JAVA_HOME`, однако `echo %JAVA_HOME%` работает.
Нахожусь я в среде Visual Studio Code 2019 с C++ (программа должна запускать .bat файл, который будет, в свою очередь, запускать .jar файл).
.bat файл выглядит вот так:

```
@echo off

cd %JAVA_HOME%\bin\
```

С чем связана данная проблема? Обязательно ли вообще переходить в директорию jdk\bin?

Comment: Добрый день, вы уверены что переменная JAVA_HOME зарегистрирована в системе? Что выдает echo %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: @Вадим `echo %JAVA_HOME%` сейчас выдало `%JAVA_HOME%`, хотя раньше выдавало путь. Автоматически ли Java выставляет эту переменную при установке или ее нужно обязательно объявить вручную?

Comment: Попробуй поставить https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#mn. Там всё за тебя пропишут.

Comment: @bombmus честно сказать не встречал чтобы автоматом данная переменная создавалась. Во любом случае в данной ситуации ее необходимо вам создать.